# Making my data fit Keras Sequential Models and Dense Layers and produce output

Tags: python, theano, keras

I have structured data that looks like this.

```
faults.head()

Fault   DEALER  FAILMODE    FAILCODEMODE    DAYS UNTIL FAILURE  TERRITORY CODE  DESIGN PHASE CODE   PLANT ID CODE
0   CAMPAIGN/TRP    31057   CAMPAIGN    BNRBC1  283.0   102 62  82
1   INTERMITTENT PROBL  24126   SPECIAL (NO FAILURE)    XXIPNF  126.0   102 62  82
2   DSID #DSBCG2058 TAG #362783 EXHAUST SYSTEM. U...    0   CLOGGED, PLUGGED WITH FOREIGN MATERIAL, DIRT/D...   USDVDR  118.0   102 62  82
3   INTERMITTENT PROBL  20943   SPECIAL (NO FAILURE)    XXIPNF  97.0    102 62  82
4   CAMPAIGN    19134   CAMPAIGN    USSCR1  315.0   102 62  82
```

I'm trying to predict the class FAILMODE. There's only 122 unique values in FAILMODE. Those are my classes.

Based on all the other data in the rows, I want to have a one-hot matrix or even the class itself be a product of the computation on my test set. Here's my code so far-

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
Using Theano backend.

faults_testing = faults[:14843]
faults_training = faults[14844:]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(len(faults.FAILMODE.unique()) + 20, input_dim=len(faults_training), init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(len(faults_training), init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(len(faults.FAILMODE.unique()), init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Here is where the tutorial says-

```
model.fit(X, Y, nb_epoch=len(faults_training), batch_size=10)
```

I don't know what X or Y is so I just tried the following-

```
model.fit(faults_training['FAILMODE'], faults_testing['FAILMODE'], nb_epoch=len(faults_training), batch_size=10)
```

It resulted in this error-

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-e8765933cfb9> in <module>()
----> 1 model.fit(faults_training['FAILMODE'], faults_testing['FAILMODE'], nb_epoch=len(faults_training), batch_size=10)

ValueError: Error when checking model input: expected dense_input_1 to have shape (None, 34631) but got array with shape (34631L, 1L)
```

Please be thorough with your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Regular neural network (including Keras Sequential model) only accepts float for data (X) and int or one-hot-encoding for label/class (Y). So you need to convert your dataset to match the requirements. So what you may want to do:

1. Map all categorical (string) values (eg. CAMPAIGN/TRP, BNRBC1, XXIPNF) to float (it will be better if you can normalize the data)
2. Put all the data columns (excluding the label column) in X
3. Put the label column (should be 1 column only) inside Y and convert to one-hot-encoding using [to_categorical](https://keras.io/utils/np_utils/) eg `Y = to_categorical(Y)`
4. Split the training and testing data using function such as [train_test_split](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) `X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33)`
5. Train the model using `model.fit(X_train, Y_train, nb_epoch=100, batch_size=10)`. Adjust the `nb_epoch` and `batch_size` later on based on your expectation of speed and accuracy of the training
6. Evaluate the accuracy using `scores = model.evaluate(self, X_test, Y_test, batch_size=10)`

You can also check this article to get idea how to convert categorical data to numeric http://fastml.com/converting-categorical-data-into-numbers-with-pandas-and-scikit-learn/

Comment: I'm trying what your saying, which seems to be the right approach, but now I'm getting `ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [49475, 6035950]` when I do the `train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33`. When I do `Y = to_categorical(Y)`, `len(Y)` is now 6035950 when it should be 49745 before the split. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us the code that you use to transform the dataframe to X & Y?